# How do I make a trailing slash optional with webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm using the new webapp2 (now the default webapp in 1.6), and I haven't been able to figure out how to make the trailing slash optional in code like this:

```
webapp.Route('/feed', handler = feed)
```

I've tried `/feed/?`, `/feed/*`, `/feed\/*` and `/feed\/?`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid creating duplicate URL:s to the same page, you should use a RedirectRoute with strict_slash set to True to automatically redirect /feed/ to /feed, like this:

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute

route = RedirectRoute('/feed', handler=feed, strict_slash=True)
```

Read more at http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to say that if I have a hundred routes, I need a hundred redirectroutes as well? Seems a terribly messy solution.

Comment: Hi. No, you replace the Routes with RedirectRoutes, so you don't need both. RedirectRoute does all that Route does, but also adds the "strict_slash" option, as well as some other redirect functionality. Check out the link I posted above for details.

Comment: This is not always a good idea. If your client isn't a web browser (eg, if you're writing an http-accessible api for your website), it may not follow the redirect.

Answer (score 7):

I don't like the `RedirectRoute` class because it causes an unnecessary **HTTP Redirect**.
Based on the documentation for [webapp2 Route class](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route), here is a more detailed answer in this [webapp2.Route with optional leading part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942119/138284) thread.

**Short Answer**

My route patterns works for the following URLs.

1. /
2. /feed
3. /feed/
4. /feed/create
5. /feed/create/
6. /feed/edit/{entity_id}

```py
SITE_URLS = [
    webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=HomePageHandler, name='route-home'),

    webapp2.Route(r'/feed/<:(create/?)|edit/><entity_id:(\d*)>',
        handler=MyFeedHandler,
        name='route-entity-create-or-edit'),

    webapp2.SimpleRoute(r'/feed/?',
        handler=MyFeedListHandler,
        name='route-entity-list'),
]
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I handle these routes.

```
from webapp2 import Route
from webapp2_extras.routes import PathPrefixRoute
import handlers

urls = [
  Route('/foo<:/?>', handlers.Foo),
  Route('/bars', handlers.BarList),
  PathPrefixRoute('/bar', [
    Route('/', handlers.BarList),
    Route('/<bar_id:\w+><:/?>', handlers.Bar),
  ]),
]
...
```

It's important to note that your handlers will need to define `*args` and `**kwargs` to deal with the potential trailing slash, which gets sent to them as an argument using this method.

```
class Bar(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(bar_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # Lookup and render this Bar using bar_id.
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`webapp2.Route` template is not a regular expressions and your value is being escaped with `re.escape`. You can use old style rules which provides regular expression templates:

```
 webapp2.SimpleRoute('^/feed/?$', handler = feed)
```

Comment: I want to continue using webapps' own syntax without dropping down to regular regular expressions... in that sense the `strict_slash` gives me exactly what I want with the least code changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to make the trailling slash on the root of a PathPrefixRoute block optional.

If you have, say:

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute, PathPrefixRoute

from webapp2 import Route

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  PathPrefixRoute('admin', [
      RedirectRoute('/', handler='DashboardHandler', name='admin-dashboard', strict_slash=True),
      RedirectRoute('/sample-page/', handler='SamplePageHandler', name='sample-page', strict_slash=True),
  ]),
])
```

You will be able to access `/admin/`, but not `/admin`.

Since I couldn't find any better solution, I've added a `redirect_to_name` to an extra route, like:

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute, PathPrefixRoute

from webapp2 import Route

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  Route('admin', handler='DashboardHandler', name='admin-dashboard'),
  PathPrefixRoute('admin', [
      RedirectRoute('/', redirect_to_name='admin-dashboard'),
      RedirectRoute('/sample-page/', handler='SamplePageHandler', name='sample-page', strict_slash=True),
  ]),
])
```

I'm interested in better solutions to this problem.

Should I go for Stun's solution and simply not use RedirectRoute?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and is very simple. It uses the template format for URI routing in the webapp2 Route [class](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route.__init__). Trailing slash in this example is optional with no redirection:

```
webapp2.Route('/your_url<:/?>', PageHandler)
```

Everything after the colon between the chevrons is considered to be a regex: `<:regex>`

Comment: Worth noting your methods need the extra argument, which kinda sucks.

Comment: I pass `*args, **kwargs` into my methods anyway, so the `get` for `PageHandler` would be `def get(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use redirects (and you probably don't), you can override `Route.match()`:

```
from webapp2 import Route, _get_route_variables
import urllib
from webob import exc


class SloppyRoute(Route):
    """
    A route with optional trailing slash.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SloppyRoute, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def match(self, request):
        path = urllib.unquote(request.path)
        match = self.regex.match(path)
        try:
            if not match and not path.endswith('/'):
                match = self.regex.match(path + '/')
        except:
            pass
        if not match or self.schemes and request.scheme not in self.schemes:
            return None

        if self.methods and request.method not in self.methods:
            # This will be caught by the router, so routes with different
            # methods can be tried.
            raise exc.HTTPMethodNotAllowed()

        args, kwargs = _get_route_variables(match, self.defaults.copy())
        return self, args, kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a sort of hacky way. I define the following class:

```
class UrlConf(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.confs = []
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, webapp2.Route):
                slash_route = webapp2.Route(arg.template + '/', arg.handler)
                self.confs += [arg, slash_route]

    def __iter__(self):
        for route in self.confs:
            yield route
```

Then I set up my routes like the following:

```
MIRROR_URLS = list(UrlConf(
    Route('/path/to/stuff', handler=StuffHandler, name='stuff.page'),
    Route('/path/to/more/stuff', handler= MoreStuffHandler, name='more.stuff.page')
))
```

If you do choose to go this route, you can obviously improve upon it to be more flexible with other types of BaseRoute objects.

Answer (score -4):

I am not familiar with webapp2, but if the first parameter is a regular expression, try:

```
/feed(/)?
```